# System freezes including keyboard/mouse

Tags: nvidia, google-chrome, freeze

I'm a brand new linux/ubuntu user, and i'm having some issues with freezes.

The first time it happened it did so without any warning, and i had to do a hard reboot.

The second time, it started with Google Chrome, and then firefox, and then system settings, and then, the terminal froze along with everything else. Again, had to do a hard reboot.

I am running ubuntu on a i7 4770k
Asus Maximus VI motherboard
Corsair DDR3 memory 16gb
Intel 80gb SSD
Gigabyte geforce 970GTX G1 Gaming videocard

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience points to the likelihood of graphics card & driver issues.

Open up a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>) and run the following commands.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && software-properties-gtk --open-tab=4
```

You'll have to type in your password. Then you may have to type a 'y' to confirm some downloads. After the Ubuntu is updated the "additional drivers" tab in the software center will open. You can view and update your graphics drivers there.

Here's a brief explanation of the first two commands.  `sudo apt-get update` updates packages from repositories. `sudo apt-get upgrade` actually installs those packages. These two steps are prerequisite for the third step of selecting an updated graphics card driver.

Give it a shot and tell us your progress!

Comment: Thank you! I tried this out and so far no issues!

Answer (score 1):

I had this problems for a couple of weeks now. My system wouldn't last 30 mn. I had to restart. So this morning I checked my proprietary driver (NVIDIA ) which was not​ in use. And since i enable it... For about 5 hours now everything is fine.
I'm using Ubuntu 17.04 on a latitude e6420, i5 and 6Go Ram. 
Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to check is if your system is automatically overclocking, I've run into that problem in a few situations especially with gaming equipment. Some overclocking done on the BIOS level can lead to instability during normal use.